# Unexpected token when typing a function with destructuring assignment parameters in Create-React-App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm currently trying to define the type for a function whose parameters implement the destructuring assgnment syntax, for example

```
type somefunc = ({name} : {name: string}) => boolean;
```

It is giving me the following compile time error:

> ./src/App.tsx SyntaxError: /apps/src/App.tsx: Unexpected token,
>   expected ")" (9:24)

It highlights the error on the `:` between `{name}` and `{name: string}`. However, I understand that this is the intended way to type destructure assignment parameters for a function.

My node version is `node v10.13.0` while my react-scripts version is `react-scripts v2.1.1`, which should be sufficiently up-to-date.

How could I make the compiler understand this syntax?

Comment: What is the left-hand side there supposed to be doing? `{name} :`? Did you mean `name :`?

Comment: Its supposed to define that this function's first parameter uses the destructuring assignment syntax. @CertainPerformance But after reading ttulka's answer, I realize now that this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to type the parameter in the declaration of the function type, you should write it like:

```
type somefunc = (param : {name: string}) => boolean;
```

It says, the function (`=>`) returns a `boolean` and takes one parameter of type object `{...}` with an attribute `name` of type `string`.

And then you can use destructuring in the definition of the function:

```
const myfn: somefunc = ({name}) =>  {
    console.log('Name: ', name);
    return true;
}

myfn({name: 'John'});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. The original typing I used in this question worked on a project that wasn't using create-react-app, but instead used my own configurations with Babel, so I assumed that it should work here also. It seems that there are some inconsistencies.